# How to make MenuStrip on the same level as closing/minimising buttons using WinForms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I wonder if this can be done witout disabling FormBorderStyle, if not, then how to add exactly the same buttons as in Win 10 default closing buttons. Or how to make this design(MenuStrip on the same row with closing/minimizing buttons as in VS 2019) using Windows Forms?[image]

Comment: No you might disable showing top bar and implement the row includes menustrip left and the group of buttons right

Comment: VS2019 is based on WPF, not WinForms. If you want similar effect in WinForms, you have to render title bar with your own customization. Not an easy task if you just start to learn WinForms.